# Remove PHP errors from CLI and PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm currently getting the following errors when using PHP via command line and on PHPMyAdmin.

[Command line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XF2ly.png)

[PHPMyAdmin error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWC0v.png)

What's the easiest way to disable these errors? The command line errors don't make sense because all them work correctly.

When I navigate to the directory where it's saying it doesn't exist, it's .so version of them not .dll.

Tried disabling them in php.ini but didn't do anything.

Comment: You don't disable errors.. you ***fix*** them!

Comment: fix them, looks like something went wrong during installation or configured wrong.

Comment: You're trying to load PHP DLLs in Linux? Did you by any chance download a php.ini for Windows?

Comment: for PHPMyAdmin an update to one corresponding to your PHP version should fix these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your command line screenshot it can be seen that you have unix path and windows `.dll` - it is a nonsense. You need to look at your php.ini and fix either `extension_dir` or `extension` entries.

For phpMyAdmin errors you need to edit `error_reporting` into your php.ini to e.g. `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED`

Comment: Commented the .dll out and no errors. I was under the impression it was required.
Also, the PHPMyAdmin issue is fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

The accepted solution is wrong. It will turn off all error reporting in PHP and that's not intended?

The best way to turn off Phpmyadmin errors is to go go config.inc.php and set (or comment out ie removing the // lines in front of the value, which is set to "ask" by default.)

```
$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';
```

Hit save and that's it.

More info
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_SendErrorReports